# What's wrong with my formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

In Google Sheets:
First, I'd like to return the values in the whole column of D into Column H if:

1. E and F equal A and B
2. C is *not* blank

This was the formula I tried:
=IF(ISBLANK(C2=TRUE),"",(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E2:E&F2:F,{A2:A&B2:B,C2:D},4,FALSE))))

Second, I'd like to return the values in the whole column of D in Column I if:

1. E and F equal A and B
2. C *is* blank

Here's what I tried:
=IF(ISBLANK(C2=TRUE),ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E2:E&F2:F,{A2:A&B2:B,C2:D},4,FALSE)),"")

Neither work though... What am I doing wrong? Here's an image of the spreadsheet:
[image: Both formulas are in Row 2 of H and I respectively.]

Answer (score 0):

To get aggregate results, use `vlookup()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(E2:E & F2:F), 
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        E2:E & F2:F, 
        query( 
          { A2:A & B2:B, isblank(C2:C), D2:D }, 
          "select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 
          0 
        ), 
        { 2, 3 }, false 
      ) 
    ), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula goes into cell `H2` and will fill the whole column. Clear columns `H2:I` before you apply the formula to make room for the results.

> (outdated):
> To get row-by-row results, use [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra), like this:
>
> ```
> =arrayformula( 
>   if( 
>     (E2:E = A2:A) * (F2:F = B2:B), 
>     { 
>       if( not(isblank(C2:C)), D2:D, iferror(1/0) ), 
>       if( isblank(C2:C), D2:D, iferror(1/0) ) 
>     }, 
>     iferror(1/0) 
>   ) 
> )
> ```
>
> See [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) and [arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275).

Comment: Thanks for your help! For whatever reason, that only returns (Edit: just found out carriage return sends...) the first value in H, and nothing in I. I did make sure I completely cleared H and I.

Comment: Edited the answer. Consider showing your desired results so that we know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

```
=MAP(E2:E,F2:F,LAMBDA(e,f,
    {SUM(IFNA(FILTER(D:D,A:A=e,B:B=f,C:C<>""))),
SUM(IFNA(FILTER(D:D,A:A=e,B:B=f,C:C="")))}

))
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. As with doubleunary's recommendation, this only returns one value. The only difference is that it returns the value in I2.

This leads me to believe that I'm doing something wrong. I just don't know what it is. Any thoughts?

Comment: See update. You were trying to do some lookup to consolidate data, we understood you were doing some logical comparison row by row

Comment: Thanks! That worked, except for a few rows. Wish I could post a pic here... here's the error though: 
Error
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 2. Actual: 1.

Comment: Try again to see if you may have duplicates, SUM would group them.